# How do I find all maxima of this function?

Tags: maximum

I have to find all the maxima of the function

```
fun[t_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[1/y^(11/3) Cos[y t], {y, 1, 2 }]
```

To find the poit with zero first derivative I have done:

```
Reduce[1/y^(11/3) Cos[y t] == 0, t]
```

with  result:

```
C[1] \[Element] Integers &&  y != 0 && (t == (-(\[Pi]/2) + 2 \[Pi] C[1])/y ||  t == (\[Pi]/2 + 2 \[Pi] C[1])/y)
```

Now how do I find which of these points are the maxima? I tought to use the second derivative of `fun[t]`, which is the first derivative of the function inside the integral, but I don't know how to use the result of `Reduce`

Comment: I think `fun'[t]` is given by `Integrate[D[1/y^(11/3) Cos[y t], t], {y, 1, 2}]`.  (You can also find the integral for `fun` symbolically as well, which might make finding the maxima easier.)

Comment: Have you tried `NMaximize`? It seems the global maximum is at `t==0`, with `fun[0] == -(3/64) (-8 + 2^(1/3)) == 0.315941`. You can use `FindMaximum` for the local maxima (e.g., there next maxima are at $\pm$ `4.976`, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fun[t_] = Integrate[1/y^(11/3) Cos[y t], {y, 1, 2}] // Simplify

(* 1/2 (ExpIntegralE[11/3, -I t] + ExpIntegralE[11/3, I t]) - (
 ExpIntegralE[11/3, -2 I t] + ExpIntegralE[11/3, 2 I t])/(8 2^(2/3)) *)
```

[`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) `fun` to obtain initial estimates for use with [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
plt = Plot[fun[t], {t, -15, 15},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

```
sol = FindRoot[fun'[t] == 0, {t, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@ 
  Range[-10, 10, 5]

(* {{t -> -11.0583535838776}, {t -> -4.97614346331708}, {t -> 0}, {t -> 
   4.97614346331708}, {t -> 11.0583535838776}} *)
```

Visually verifying:

```
Show[plt, Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{t, fun[t]} /. sol]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The n-th maxima can be computed using

```
nthMax[n_Integer] := Quiet[
                      FindMaximum[
                       NIntegrate[1/y^(11/3) Cos[y t], {y, 1, 2}]
                      , {t, -8 + 2 π n}]
                     , {NIntegrate::inumr}]
nthMax /@ Range[5] // TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.315941 & \{t\to -\text{2.189*${}^{\wedge}$-16}\} \\
 0.148796 & \{t\to 4.97614\} \\
 0.0821207 & \{t\to 11.0584\} \\
 0.0553822 & \{t\to 17.269\} \\
 0.0415163 & \{t\to 23.5158\} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If you want an analytic formula for large $n$, you can use
$$
-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{64+8\ 2^{2/3}}+3 \sqrt[3]{2}}{8+\sqrt[3]{2}}}\right)+2 \pi  n+\frac{1+\frac{6}{\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}}}{(3 \pi ) n}+\mathcal O(1/n^2)
$$

Here is the numeric result minus the asyptotic expansion, keeping the $\mathcal O(n),\mathcal O(1)$, and $\mathcal O(1/n)$ approximations, respectively:

[image]